# Validating a Battleship board, 2d array, how to check possibilities for boards validity?

Tags: java, puzzle

writing a code in Java to validate a battleship board when given a 2d array with 1's and 0's where 1 is a part of a ship and the 0 is the sea.
here are the rules to know:

-There must be single battleship (size of 4 cells), 2 cruisers (size 3), 3 destroyers (size 2) and 4 submarines (size 1). Any additional ships are not allowed, as well as missing ships.

-Each ship must be a straight line, except for submarines, which are just single cell.

**-The ship cannot overlap, but can be contact with any other ship.**

my approach was just to count all the possible connections for the size 2 size 3 size 4 ships and make sure they are bigger than the amount of the size ship required, this doesn't work for every scenario, also I would help check if there  are exactly 20 placements with 1's problem is that if we have 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 it will tell me that it is valid although it is definitely not(since its one row and one ship) and when I have the following:
should be false but mine returns true->

```
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0},
 {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},
 {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},
```

or
which should be false but mine returns true->

```
 {0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0},
 {0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0},
 {0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0},
 {0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
```

here is an example where the code works when it should return true:

```
 {1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},
 {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0},
 {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
```

but when I have this example:

```
{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},
 {0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1},
 {0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
```

should be false but my code returns true. so how can I find a way to restructure my code or have a solution which when I am given a board I wouldn't really know whether its valid or not. but my Java program will?

here is my code with what I attempted for this, my approach here is to make a list with all the variations of checking specific ships from biggest to smaller(biggest would be [4 3 3 2 2 2] not including 1's since it will significantly raise the amount of variations and I can just check it differently and more efficiently, smallest variation would be [2 2 2 3 3 4] 4 last the reason they are repeated is because for 2 there are x3 ships so 2 2 2, x2 size 3 ships so 3 3 and x1 size 4 ship so just one) here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Permute{
    public static List<int[]> l;
    Permute(){
        this.l=new ArrayList<int[]>();
    }
    static void permute(java.util.List<Integer> arr, int k){
        for(int i = k; i < arr.size(); i++){
            java.util.Collections.swap(arr, i, k);
            permute(arr, k+1);
            java.util.Collections.swap(arr, k, i);
        }
        if (k == arr.size() -1){
            l.add(arr.stream()
            .map(i -> (i == null ? 0 : i))
            .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
            .toArray()); 
        }
    }
     public static List<int[]> get(){
        Permute.permute(java.util.Arrays.asList(2,2,2,3,3,4), 0);Collections.reverse(l);
        return l;
    }
}

public class BF {
    private static int[][] fields,copy;
    private static int[] ship= {0,0,3,2,1};
    public BF(int[][] field) {
        fields=field;
//        print(field);
        this.copy=field;
    }
    
    public boolean validate() {
        int cnt=counter(fields);
        if(cnt!=20)return false;
        Permute p= new Permute();//permutation constructor
        List<int[]> list=p.get();//gets our specific permution
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {//run through each option of our permution list
            copy=fields;
            ship=new int[]{0,0,3,2,1};//amount of ships needed
            boolean flag=check(fields,list.get(i));//checks if the permution variation is true or false
            int cnt1=counter(copy);//we checked boats of size 2 3 4 but not 1 which means if its valid then there should be 4 boats left
            if(flag && cnt1==4)return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
   public static boolean check(int[][] field,int[] ships){
           for(int i=0;i<ships.length;i++) {//go through the array and loop through the variation
                int num=getBoat(fields, ships[i]);//if the boat is true on the certain boat we are checking
                ship[num]--;//then -1 and at the end we want it to be [<=0,0,0,0,0]
           }
           int counter=0;
           for(int i=2;i<ship.length;i++) {
               if(ship[i]==0)counter++;//if [0,0,0]
           }
           if(counter==3) {return true;}//then return true
         return false;
    }

  public static int getBoat(int[][] field,int num) {
      int dire=0,r=0,c=0;String dir="row";
     for (int col = 0; col < fields[0].length; col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < fields.length; row++) {//loop through each coordinate
            if (copy[row][col] == 1) {//check if its part of a boat at the coor
              int length=field.length;dir="row";dire=row;
               for(int j=0;j<2;j++) {//go horizontal then vertical
                   if(j==1) {length=field[0].length;dir="col";dire=col;}//change length to vertical
                    if(dire+num-1<length) {//make sure we don't get outofbounds error
                        int cnt=0;
                        for(int i=0;i<num;i++) {//checks each coor according to type of boat we are checking
                            if(dir.equals("row")) {r=row+i;c=col;}
                            else if(dir.equals("col")){r=row;c=col+i;}
                            if(copy[r][c]==1) {//check
                                cnt++;//copy of battle field becomes 0
                            }
                            else copy=fields;//otherwise break this loop since it is not relevant anymore on this coor
                            if(cnt==num) {
                                for(int k=0;k<num;k++) {
                                    if(dir.equals("row")) {r=row+k;c=col;}
                                    else if(dir.equals("col")){r=row;c=col+k;}
                                    copy[r][c]=0;//now we know its valid length and make it 0 on the copy
                                    }
                                    return cnt;
                        }}}} //if num is correct then return it
                }
        }
     }return 0;
     }
  public static int counter(int[][] f) {// counts amount of tiles on the board with 1's
      int cnt=0;
    for (int col = 0; col < f[0].length; col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < f.length; row++) {
            if (f[row][col] == 1) {
             cnt++; 
            }
            }
    }
    return cnt;
  }
    public static void print(int[][] field) {//prints the board
        for (int row = 0; row < field.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < field[0].length; col++) {
                if(col<field[0].length-1 && col!=0) {
                    System.out.print( field[row][col]+",");
                }
                else if(col==field[0].length-1){
                    System.out.print( field[row][col]+"},");
                }
                else if(col==0) {
                    System.out.print(" {"+ field[row][col]+",");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
            }
  System.out.println("\n");
    }

}
```

the code seems to run well now but doesn't return true when its suppose to.

here are some examples where the code should return true but returns false:

```
{1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},
 {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0},
 {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
```

true here:

```
 {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0},
 {0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0},
 {0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
```

true here:

```
 {1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},
 {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0},
 {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
```

true here:

```
 {1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0},
 {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
```

and true here:

```
{1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},
 {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0},
 {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
```

but the code returns false on these examples

so in this example

```
 {1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0},
 {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
```

it valid because:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

but my code takes the first option of size and this is what happens which my code returns as false-

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

so what do I need to add to fix this problem?

```
public class BF {
    private static int[][] fields;
    public BF(int[][] field) {
        fields=field;
        print(field);
        
    }
    public boolean validate() {
        int cnt=counter(fields);
        if(cnt!=20)return false;
        return checkBoard(fields, new int[]{4,3,3,2,2,2},0,new int[] {3,2,1});
    }


    public static boolean checkBoard(int[][] board,int[] SizePlacement,int k,int[] shipAmount){
       if (counter(board)==4 ) {
            return true;
        }
       int cnt=0;//SizePlacement={4,3,3,2,2,2}, ship(changes)={3,2,1}, k(starts at 0) is placement in ships[]
       for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
           for (int col = 0; col < board[0].length; col++) {
             if(board[row][col]==1 && row+SizePlacement[k]<board.length) {//vertically
               cnt=1;
               for(int i=1;i<SizePlacement[k];i++) {//check vertically
                   if(board[row+i][col]==1) {cnt++;}
                   }
               if(cnt>=SizePlacement[k]) {
                   int[][] newBoard = deepcopy(board);
                   newBoard= remove(newBoard , row, col, SizePlacement[k], "ver");
                   shipAmount[SizePlacement[k]-2]--;
                   if(shipAmount==new int[]{0,0,0}) {return true;}
                   if(k+1<SizePlacement.length && checkBoard(newBoard,SizePlacement,k+1,shipAmount)) {return true;}
                  shipAmount[SizePlacement[k]-2]++;   
               }
           }
            if(board[row][col]==1 && col+SizePlacement[k]<board[0].length) {//horizontally
               cnt=1;
               for(int i=1;i<SizePlacement[k];i++) {//check horizontally
                   if(board[row][col+i]==1) {cnt++;}
                   }
               if(cnt>=SizePlacement[k]) {
                  int[][] newBoard = deepcopy(board);
                  newBoard= remove(newBoard , row, col, SizePlacement[k], "hor");
                   shipAmount[SizePlacement[k]-2]--;
                   if(shipAmount==new int[]{0,0,0}) {return true;}
                   if(k+1<SizePlacement.length &&checkBoard(newBoard,SizePlacement,k+1,shipAmount)) {
                     return true;
                   }
                  shipAmount[SizePlacement[k]-2]++;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       return false;
    }
   public static int[][] remove(int[][] newBoard,int row,int col,int size,String orien){
       int[][] removedBoard= deepcopy(newBoard);
       if(orien=="ver") {
           for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
               removedBoard[row+i][col]=0;
           }
           print(removedBoard);
           return removedBoard;
       }
       else if(orien=="hor") {
           for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
               removedBoard[row][col+i]=0;
           }
           print(removedBoard);
           return removedBoard;
       }
       return removedBoard;
   }
   public static int[][] deepcopy(int[][] fields){
    int[][] copy= new int[fields.length][fields[0].length];
    for (int row = 0; row < fields.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < fields[0].length; col++) {
                   copy[row][col]= fields[row][col];
               }
            }
    return copy;
   }
   public static int counter(int[][] f) {// counts amount of tiles on the board with 1's
          int cnt=0;
        for (int col = 0; col < f[0].length; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < f.length; row++) {
                if (f[row][col] == 1) {
                 cnt++; 
                }
                }
        }
        return cnt;
      }
        public static void print(int[][] field) {//prints the board
            for (int row = 0; row < field.length; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < field[0].length; col++) {
                    if(col<field[0].length-1 && col!=0) {
                        System.out.print( field[row][col]+",");
                    }
                    else if(col==field[0].length-1){
                        System.out.print( field[row][col]+"},");
                    }
                    else if(col==0) {
                        System.out.print(" {"+ field[row][col]+",");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");
                }
      System.out.println("\n");
        }
}
```

this seems to have some kinda bug(different from the solution), not sure help on this would be appreciated
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX32n.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFP1N.png

Comment: Could you check each row/column to see if they contain consecutive 1s, and if so add them to a counter of each ship? At the end, make sure each type of ship has been counted the correct number of times.

Comment: Why not mark each ship with its own number, e.g. 1 - battleship. 2,3 - cruisers, etc.  This could make the validation of the board easier.

Comment: yeah you could @AdrianRusso but there can be different options like 111 is size 3 and size2

Comment: @AlexRudenko i kinda did that, i made an array called num(guess i should of called it ships) which stores the numbers- ill change it now)... so yeah I did

Comment: @Abra well your program needs to go through all the possibilities and figure out if the board is valid. the person who sets up the board is't going to tell you if its a submarine or a destroyer... I understand the concern but I prefer to keep it with 1's and 0's

Comment: I removed my initial answer, because as @Maurice Perry pointed out, it doesn't work. A backtracking algorithm is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we can't tell the ships apart with certainty we will need to try different possibilities. Try placing a ship in a possible position (reserving that position) and then try for the next ship recursively. (This is probably what others have suggested too). For a 10x10 board with this few ships the computation is pretty quick.

Here is my attempt to implement it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Main {
    private static final int SIZE = 10;
    private static final int HORIZONTAL = 0;
    private static final int VERTICAL = 1;

    private static final int[] shipSizes = {4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2};
    private static final int NR_OF_ONES = 4;

    private static final int[][] board1 = {
            {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
            {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
            {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0},
            {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

    private static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] board = board1;

        validateBoard(board);
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        boolean valid = checkBoard(board, 0);
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.println("Board is " + (valid ? "" : "NOT ") + "valid");
        System.out.println("Checked board in " + time + " ns");
    }

    private static boolean checkBoard(int[][] currentBoard, int shipSizePos) {
        if (shipSizePos >= shipSizes.length) {
            return true;
//            return countOnes(currentBoard) == NR_OF_ONES;
        }
        List<Ship> currentSizeShips = findPossibleShips(currentBoard, shipSizes[shipSizePos]);
        boolean valid = false;
        for (Ship ship : currentSizeShips) {
            if(checkBoard(removeShipFromBoard(currentBoard, ship), shipSizePos + 1)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return valid;
    }

    private static int[][] removeShipFromBoard(int[][] board, Ship ship) {
        int[][] newBoard = new int[SIZE][SIZE];
        for (int r = 0; r < SIZE; ++r) {
            for (int c = 0; c < SIZE; ++c) {
                if ((ship.orientation == HORIZONTAL && r == ship.row && (c >= ship.col && c < ship.col + ship.size))
                        || (ship.orientation == VERTICAL && c == ship.col && (r >= ship.row && r < ship.row + ship.size))) {
                    newBoard[r][c] = 0;
                } else {
                    newBoard[r][c] = board[r][c];
                }
            }
        }
        return newBoard;
    }

    private static List<Ship> findPossibleShips(int[][] board, int size) {
        List<Ship> ships = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int r = 0; r < SIZE; ++r) {
            for (int c = 0; c < SIZE; ++c) {
                if (board[r][c] == 1) {
                    if (isPossibleHorizontalShip(board, size, r, c)) {
                        ships.add(new Ship(r, c, size, HORIZONTAL));
                    }
                    if (isPossibleVerticalShip(board, size, r, c)) {
                        ships.add(new Ship(r, c, size, VERTICAL));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return ships;
    }

    private static boolean isPossibleHorizontalShip(int[][] board, int size, int row, int col) {
        if (SIZE - col < size) {
            return false;
        }
        int c;
        for (c = col; c < SIZE && board[row][c] == 1; ++c) ;
        return c - col >= size;
    }

    private static boolean isPossibleVerticalShip(int[][] board, int size, int row, int col) {
        if (SIZE - row < size) {
            return false;
        }
        int r;
        for (r = row; r < SIZE && board[r][col] == 1; ++r) ;
        return r - row >= size;
    }

    private static int countOnes(int[][] board) {
        int ones = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < SIZE; ++r) {
            for (int c = 0; c < SIZE; ++c) {
                ones += board[r][c];
            }
        }
        return ones;
    }

    private static void validateBoard(int[][] board) {
        for (int r = 0; r < SIZE; ++r) {
            for (int c = 0; c < SIZE; ++c) {
                if (!(board[r][c] == 0 || board[r][c] == 1)) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal character at " + r + ", " + c);
                }
            }
        }
        if (countOnes(board) != Arrays.stream(shipSizes).sum() + NR_OF_ONES) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong number of ship pieces");
        }
    }

    private static class Ship {
        private final int row;
        private final int col;
        private final int size;
        private final int orientation;

        public Ship(int row, int col, int size, int orientation) {
            this.row = row;
            this.col = col;
            this.size = size;
            this.orientation = orientation;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Ship ship = (Ship) o;
            return row == ship.row && col == ship.col && size == ship.size && orientation == ship.orientation;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(row, col, size, orientation);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Ship{" +
                    "row=" + row +
                    ", col=" + col +
                    ", size=" + size +
                    ", orientation=" + orientation +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

- First validates board to make sure it contains only 0s and 1s and the correct number of 1s
- Goes through the list of non size 1 ships from largest to smallest.
- Searches for possible placements for the current size, removes one and checks that branch for the next size
- When only 1s remain, the board is OK (we rely on the count from the validation to be correct)

Answer (score 2):

The board is valid if the position of all of the ships are valid.

This means you need a data structure for the ship.  To start, a simple data structure might be `[ ship_type, [ position_1 , position_2, position_3 ] ]`

Once you have data structures for the ship, it is trivial to check that all of the ships are on the board, no two ships share a single position, and the correct number of ships of each type are on the board.  Correct number of ships of each type can go into a `Fleet` data structure.

With a ship, you will quickly realize that the board for the side with awareness of its fleet can be rendered with letters for their ships.  But the other board is "special" because there is no ship visibility.  This means that (as in the real game) Battleship consists of two kinds of board, a hit-detection board and a ship positioning board.  That they look similar is only a side-effect of manufacturing.

Now for the `HitBoard` how would and AI attempt to hunt down a ship?  Well, they would start off with random placements, or a pattern.  There are advantages to both approaches.  Once a hit is detected, then it will consult the number of remaining ships on the field, and start probing along the horizontal and vertical axis to find the ship's full position.  Once it is told "You sunk my " It will know that the sunk ship  must be removed from play.

```
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
```

Consisting of two battleships, a destroyer, a submarine, and a cruiser.  Without additional information, it will be impossible to know of the majority of the ships are oriented left-to-right or top-to-bottom.

Occasionally, it is even impossible to know the ship positioning while play is occurring.  Interestingly enough, that might not always be enough information to know the position of the ship.  This sometimes occurs when the ships are in a tightly packed formation, and you sink a ship by placing an attack within a row or column (or both) of squares that already have registered hits.  In this case, your hit might not define the end of the sunk item.

If the goal is to validate the board without any extra information beyond position, then you need to take a different approach.

1. Order the ships by size.
2. Within the current board position, repeat until there are no ships available.
3. Select the largest ship.
4. Search for all possible positionings of the largest ship, generating new boards without the markings for the ship's position.
5. If the ship could not be placed, the board was not a valid board configuration.
6. If the ship list is empty and the board has markings, the board was not a valid board configuration.
7. If the ship list is empty and the board is empty, the markings were in a valid board configuration.
8. Repeat, treating all boards independently for the generated boards from step 2.

This is a brute-force approach; but, within the brute-force approach are a number of optimizations that are possible.

Comment: not sure how to do this. do you have a reference or article I can look at to understand? thx.

Comment: Creating a new data structure in Java is done by using the words `public class Ship {`  The rest is up to how you want to represent the `Ship`.

Comment: my question isn't playing a game and what to do(though its good to know:P ), its when given a board(2d array) how can I prove whether it is valid or not

Comment: You can prove if it is valid by exhaustively removing the marks in the procedure described above.  If all boats can be removed one-at-a-time, leaving a board of no marks, then you've "filled" the marks with boat positions.

Comment: pretty much what i did but it doesn't work. those I use permutions to get every variation of ships order to check like 4 3 3 2 2 2 or 3 4 3 2 2 2 ... then code but it doesn't seem to work on valid ships when I run the code... ( I didn't include 1,1,1,1 cause it will significantly increase variation possibilities) and just check that differently

Comment: You should not permute the order of checking, as a largest-first check is algorithmically ideal, and by "pretty much the same" you probably mean "slightly different"  Slight differences in approaches have big impacts on running programs.  Odds are there is a bug in your routine.  Note that my approach might have you checking dozens of different boards for the second ship placement.  If that wasn't clear, it is now.

Comment: so your saying that i should check the variation 4 3 3 2 2 2 on each board? so wouldn't permuting then reversing the list with the variation work better?

Comment: because if i don't use the permutations, then certain valid boards might end up not being valid when I run the code

Comment: If the ships fit, then finding all of the different ways you can say they fit doesn't speed up the answer.  If they can't fit from largest to smallest, they can't fit at all.  If they can fit from largest to smallest, then choosing the largest removes the most amount of remaining slots, and quickly rules out any combinations that would then prevent the largest from fitting (like placing a Destroyer with the only possible Aircraft Carrier position).  One can use a random approach, but it will be slower as it checks more dead-end possibilities.

Comment: how can i do "Search for all possible positionings of the largest ship, generating new boards without the markings for the ship's position." ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to approach this is to iteratively place ships, starting with the biggest. A rough outline of an algorithim is this:

- Select the largest ship not placed
- Consider a list of all possible placements
- For every possible placement, remove those 1s from the array, and repeat the process, without the ship you just placed

Since you aren't encoding the type of ship certain points are, you can remove points from placed ships, and continue trying to place ships. This will explode as the number of ships increase, but I think its fast enough for this small solution.

Comment: this is what i did, but it runs through to many examples therefore it isn't good enough. also I want to check multiple boards at once. plus my code has some errors.

Comment: thats pretty much my approach, it seems to kinda of work now but I'm not sure why my code isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

An attempt at a solution that does not allow contact:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class BattleFieldValidator {
  private static final int SIZE = 10;

  private static class Ship {
    public int     col;
    public int     row;
    public boolean horizontal;
    public int     size;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "size " + size + " at (" + (row + 1) + "," + (col + 1) + ") " + (horizontal ? "horizontal" : "vertical");
    }
  }

  public static void validateField(int[][] field) {
    // 10x10 field
    if(field.length != SIZE || field[0].length != SIZE) {
      throw new RuntimeException("invalid field dimensions");
    }

    // each cell 0 or 1
    for(int row = 0; row < SIZE; row++) {
      for(int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++) {
        int cellValue = field[row][col];
        if(cellValue != 0 && cellValue != 1) {
          throw new RuntimeException("invalid cell value at (" + (row + 1) + "," + (col + 1) + ")");
        }
      }
    }

    print(field);

    boolean[][] discoveredShipCells = new boolean[SIZE][SIZE];
    List<Ship> ships = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int row = 0; row < SIZE; row++) {
      for(int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++) {
        if(discoveredShipCells[row][col]) {
          continue;
        }

        if(field[row][col] == 1) {
          Ship ship = discoverShip(field, discoveredShipCells, row, col);
          ships.add(ship);
        }
      }
    }

    Collections.sort(ships, (a, b) -> b.size - a.size);
    System.out.println("discovered ships:");
    ships.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));

    if(ships.stream().filter(s -> s.size == 4).count() != 1) {
      throw new RuntimeException("battleship(size 4) count != 1");
    }

    if(ships.stream().filter(s -> s.size == 3).count() != 2) {
      throw new RuntimeException("cruiser(size 3) count != 2");
    }

    if(ships.stream().filter(s -> s.size == 2).count() != 3) {
      throw new RuntimeException("destroyer(size 2) count != 3");
    }

    if(ships.stream().filter(s -> s.size == 1).count() != 4) {
      throw new RuntimeException("submarine (size 1) count != 4");
    }

    // ok
  }

  private static Ship discoverShip(int[][] field, boolean[][] discoveredShipCells, int shipStartRow, int shipStartCol) {
    Ship ship = new Ship();
    ship.row = shipStartRow;
    ship.col = shipStartCol;

    int horizontalSize = 0;
    for(int col = ship.col; col < SIZE && field[ship.row][col] == 1; col++) {
      horizontalSize++;
      discoveredShipCells[ship.row][col] = true;
    }

    int verticalSize = 0;
    for(int row = ship.row; row < SIZE && field[row][ship.col] == 1; row++) {
      verticalSize++;
      discoveredShipCells[row][ship.col] = true;
    }

    if(horizontalSize > 1 && verticalSize > 1) {
      throw new RuntimeException("ship extending both horizontally and vertically at (" + (ship.row + 1) + "," + (ship.col + 1) + ")");
    }

    ship.horizontal = verticalSize == 1;
    ship.size = ship.horizontal ? horizontalSize : verticalSize;

    // validate ship surrounded by ocean cells
    if(ship.horizontal) {
      // left & right
      validateOceanCell(ship, field, ship.row, ship.col - 1);
      validateOceanCell(ship, field, ship.row, ship.col + ship.size);
      // top & bottom
      for(int col = ship.col - 1; col <= ship.col + ship.size; col++) {
        validateOceanCell(ship, field, ship.row - 1, col);
        validateOceanCell(ship, field, ship.row - 1, col);
      }
    }
    else {
      // top & bottom
      validateOceanCell(ship, field, ship.row - 1, ship.col);
      validateOceanCell(ship, field, ship.row + ship.size, ship.col);
      // left & right
      for(int row = ship.row - 1; row <= ship.row + ship.size; row++) {
        validateOceanCell(ship, field, row, ship.col - 1);
        validateOceanCell(ship, field, row, ship.col + 1);
      }
    }

    return ship;
  }

  private static void validateOceanCell(Ship ship, int[][] field, int row, int col) {
    if(row < 0 || row >= SIZE || col < 0 || col >= SIZE) {
      return /* outside field, ignore */;
    }

    if(field[row][col] == 1) {
      throw new RuntimeException("ship " + ship + " not surrounded by whater at (" + (row + 1) + "," + (col + 1) + ")");
    }
  }

  private static void print(int[][] field) {
    System.out.println();
    for(int row = 0; row < SIZE; row++) {
      System.out.println(Arrays.stream(field[row]).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
  }
}
```

And minimal testing:

```
public class BattleFieldTest {

  @org.junit.Test
  public void test1() {
    int[][] battleField = { //
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 }, //
        { 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 }, //
        { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 }, //
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, //
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 }, //
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 }, //
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 }, //
        { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, //
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 }, //
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };
    BattleFieldValidator.validateField(battleField);
  }

  @org.junit.Test
  public void test2() {
    int[][] battleField = { //
        { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 }, //
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 }, //
        { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 }, //
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 }, //
        { 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, //
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 }, //
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, //
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 }, //
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, //
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, };
    BattleFieldValidator.validateField(battleField);
  }
}
```

Sample output:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
discovered ships:
size 4 at (1,1) vertical
size 3 at (3,5) horizontal
size 3 at (6,5) horizontal
size 2 at (1,6) horizontal
size 2 at (2,3) vertical
size 2 at (2,9) vertical
size 1 at (5,9) horizontal
size 1 at (7,9) horizontal
size 1 at (8,4) horizontal
size 1 at (9,8) horizontal
```

Comment: thanks, though I already attempted & solved battleship validation without contact, and the rest of the rules the same, so I don't need this. plus without contact is easier to check than with contact. though your code should return true/false if the board is valid or not!

Comment: I wrote that code for your previous question. Returning a boolean is not difficult: try/catch the whole validate method and return false in case of exception, true otherwise. Would be a pity tough, because you would lose all the nice error information that you could show to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I think @AlexRudenko meant this would be easier to validate:

```
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3},
 {0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,0},
 {0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
 {0,2,0,0,3,3,3,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,1,0},
 {0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,1,0},
```